# MySQL remembers stored procedures somewhere even if I DROP the schema

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have encountered some unexpected behavior with MySQL server 5.6.26. 
mysql is hosted on Windows 7 Enterprise 64-bit SP1.

I have a schema which contains some stored procedures. If I drop the schema and create it again the procedures still magically exist.

The stored procedures in question aren't visible in information_schema.routines nor mysql.proc.

The situation is even worse because when I try to drop the procedures with DROP PROCEDURE I get error that they don't exist (Error code 1305). On the other hand I am unable to create a new procedure with the same name (Error code 1304).

Restart of the service doesn't help.

I am interested in why is this happening. I can see the stored procedures listed in MySQL Workbench in the Navigator window. Where can possibly the stored procedures be kept?

Comment: @amdixon Yes, I will edit the question to include the info.

Comment: @amdixon Windows 7 Enterprise 64-bit SP1

Comment: check this [how-do-i-find-out-if-a-procedure-or-function-exists-in-a-mysql-database](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/567/how-do-i-find-out-if-a-procedure-or-function-exists-in-a-mysql-database) and post whether the select from routines still returns the procedure record

Comment: @amdixon No, the procedure record isn't there.

Comment: You may try to find this error here - http://bugs.mysql.com, or at least ask about this behavior.

Comment: In Ubuntu 12.04 (32-bit) I can't reproduce the problem, everything works as expected.

Comment: @wchiquito I can't reproduce the problem with other schemas either.

Comment: also cant reproduce on ubuntu 14.04 x86_64

Comment: please also add the exact error numbers and messages associated with the drop procedure and create procedure

Comment: also read this [old workbench-bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=53760) and see if the issue is also present using the direct mysql cli

Comment: @amdixon The error is not related to workbench. It is present if I use the direct CLI too. The interesting thing is taht I can see the procedures listed in workbench. When I use other tools such as HeidiSQL the procedures aren't listed (makes sense because they aren't in the 'routines' table). I would be interested in the way how mysql workbench retrieves the stored procedure list. So far I am unable to find it.

Comment: `analyze table mysql.proc;` ?

Comment: @amdixon I am currently out of work. I might look at it again on Monday. Thanks for your time so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed by running:

```
mysqlcheck --auto-repair -A -u username -ppassword
```